# PostgreSQL: execute a stored function (getting an error even though the arguments have been casted)

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, stored-functions, postgresql-12

I've run into a problem I couldn't find a solution to.

I've successfully created a function. Here's the function name and arguments:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION app_private.create_user(username citext, email text, email_is_verified boolean, name text, avatar_url text, title text DEFAULT NULL::text, color character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying, user_role smallint DEFAULT 0, password text DEFAULT NULL::text)
RETURNS app_public.users
....
CREATE FUNCTION
```

I've also successfully granted privilege to execute the function to a role. AND also created a comment:

```
grant execute on function app_private.create_user(username citext, email text, email_is_verified bool, name text, avatar_url text, title text, color varchar(7), user_role smallint, password text) to nine_manager;
GRANT    
comment on function app_private.create_user(username citext, email text, email_is_verified bool, name text, avatar_url text, title text, color varchar(7), user_role smallint, password text) is  
    E'Creates a user account.';
COMMENT
```

however, when I try to create a test user by querying:

```
SELECT "app_private.create_user"('JS0'::citext, 'test@gmail.com'::text, true::boolean, 'John Smith'::text, 'SY'::text, 'Manager'::text, '#000000'::varchar(7), 5::SMALLINT, 'test'::text);
```

I get an error:

> ERROR:  function app_private.create_user(citext, text, boolean, text, text, text, character varying, smallint, text) does not exist
>      LINE 1: SELECT "app_private.create_user"('SY0'::citext, 'test@gmail....

I've tried changing the queries and casts but failed. Nearly pulling my hair out.

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: `SELECT "app_private"."create_user"` or remove all those dreaded double quotes completely

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you. I read somewhere to add double quotes for names with a period in between, oops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove double qoutes before calling your function in select as below

```
     Select app_private.create_user(....)
      From table;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Removing the quotes worked!
(I feel like an idiot...)